# lm() saving residuals with group_by with R- confused spss user

Tags: r, spss, lm, exp

*This is complete reEdit of my orignal question*

Let's assume I'm working on RT data gathered in a repeated measure experiment. As part of my usual routine I always transform RT to natural logarytms and then compute a Z score for each RT **within each partipant adjusting for trial number**. This is typically done with a simple regression in SPSS syntax:

```
split file by subject.

REGRESSION
  /MISSING LISTWISE
  /STATISTICS COEFF OUTS R ANOVA
  /CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10)
  /NOORIGIN 
  /DEPENDENT rtLN
  /METHOD=ENTER trial
  /SAVE ZRESID.

split file off.
```

To reproduce same procedure in R generate data:

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr); library(magrittr)

#generate data
    ob<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
    ob<-factor(ob)
    trial<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6)
    rt<-c(300,305,290,315,320,320,350,355,330,365,370,370,560,565,570,575,560,570)
    cond<-c("first","first","first","snd","snd","snd","first","first","first","snd","snd","snd","first","first","first","snd","snd","snd")

    #Following variable is what I would get after using SPSS code
    ZreSPSS<-c(0.4207,0.44871,-1.7779,0.47787,0.47958,-0.04897,0.45954,0.45487,-1.7962,0.43034,0.41075,0.0407,-0.6037,0.0113,0.61928,1.22038,-1.32533,0.07806)

    sym<-data.frame(ob, trial, rt, cond, ZreSPSS)
```

I could apply a formula (blend of Mark's and Daniel's solution) to compute residuals from a `lm(log(rt)~trial)` regression but for some reason `group_by` is not working here

```
sym %<>% 
  group_by (ob) %>% 
    mutate(z=residuals(lm(log(rt)~trial)),
    obM=mean(rt), obSd=sd(rt), zRev=z*obSd+obM)
```

Resulting values clearly show that grouping hasn't kicked in.
Any idea why it didn't work out?

Comment: Can you post an example data set? Examples of the work you have done so far would go a long ways towards telling people what help you need. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more on how to ask good R questions.

Comment: Mark, ive rewritten my original question to follow your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `magrittr`, you should be able to calculate z-scores within individual with this code (it breaks things into the groups you tell it to, then calculates within that group).

```
experiment %<>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(rtLN = log(rt)
         , ZRE1 = scale(rtLN))
```

You should then be able to do use that in your model. However, one thing that may help your shift to R thinking is that you can likely build your model directly, instead of having to make all of these columns ahead of time. For example, using `lme4` to treat `subject` as a random variable:

```
withRandVar <-
  lmer(log(rt) ~ cond + (1|as.factor(subject))
       , data = experiment)
```

Then, the residuals should already be on the correct scale. Further, if you use the z-scores, you probably *should* be plotting on that scale. I am not actually sure what running with the z-scores as the response gains you -- it seems like you would lose information about the degree of difference between the groups.

That is, if the groups are tight, but the difference between them varies by subject, a z-score may always show them as a similar number of z-scores away. Imagine, for example, that you have two subjects, one scores (1,1,1) on condition A and (3,3,3) on condition B, and a second subject that scores (1,1,1) and (5,5,5) -- both will give z-scores of (-.9,-.9,-.9) vs (.9,.9,.9) -- losing the information that the difference between A and B is larger in subject 2.

If, however, you really want to convert back, you can probably use this to store the subject means and sds, then multiply the residuals by `subjSD` and add `subjMean`.

```
experiment %<>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(rtLN = log(rt)
         , ZRE1 = scale(rtLN)
         , subjMean = mean(rtLN)
         , subjSD = sd(rtLN))
```

Comment: Mark,  thank you.  I'll test your solution this evening.  As a side note,  the reason I really want to convert back to msec is this : I compute z scores only because I want to adjust for the fact that conservative trials tend to slow down response latency.  I might run similar procedures adjusting for response extremity,  which almost always speeds up latencies as response are more extreme. While analysis on those Z values yield stronger effects,  mean msec presented on plots are more readable (I guess).

Comment: *consecutive not conservative,  sorry.  I'm typing from a mobile

Comment: I was trying to use your code but can't really make it to work for my example. I replaced ' mutate(rtLN = log(rt)
         , ZRE1 = scale(rtLN))' with something like 'mutate(rtLN = log(rt)) %>%
         mutate(ZRE1 = rstandard(lm(rtLN~trial)))' As what I really need in the Zscores is the residual from  a regression but R won't accept this syntax. Any chance you could update your answer to match that scenario?

Comment: My last try was `group_by(sym, ob) %>% mutate(z=residuals(lm(log(rt)~trial)))

residuals(lm(log(rt)~trial))` this works for computing z scores from a lm() function but fails to take split_by into consideration

Comment: Correction `group_by(sym, ob) %>% mutate(z=residuals(lm(log(rt)~trial)))` works for computing z scores from a lm() function but fails to take split_by into consideration (can I edit / delete dupe comments?)

Comment: `mutate` and the other `dplyr` verbs are designed to work on data.frames. They can be forced to work with more complicated data types(like models), but that is usually tricky. Instead, I strongly suggest that you generate the data you want, then pass it separately to the model function.

Comment: Thing is, that I what I'm trying to do involves both spliting (group_by) and saving a model outcome (lm()). Could you please suggest what kind of function look for that might work here?

Comment: Do you want a separate model for each group? Then you want `do`, but you're question implied you wanted one model, just with the scores standardized within group. This may require a different question. The general guidelines are to accept answers that solve *this* problem, then ask a different question. That way, others can see the original question and answers

Comment: I might have asked the wrong question or wasn't explicit about the given SPSS code.

Comment: Indeed I want to calculate `residuals(lm(log(rt)~rt))` for each participant `subject` variable separately

Answer (score 1):

```
mylm <- lm(x~y)
rstandard(mylm)
```

This returns the standardized residuals of the function. To bind these to a variable you can do:

```
zresid <- rstandard(mylm)
```

EXAMPLE:

```
a<-rnorm(1:10,10)
b<-rnorm(1:10,10)
mylm <- lm(a~b)
mylm.zresid<-rstandard(mylm)
```

See also:

```
summary(mylm)
```

and

```
mylm$coefficients   
mylm$fitted.values  
mylm$xlevels
mylm$residuals      
mylm$assign         
mylm$call
mylm$effects        
mylm$qr             
mylm$terms
mylm$rank           
mylm$df.residual    
mylm$model
```

Comment: Sorry for double comment - how about the 2nd part? How can I transform those residuals back to their original scale, considering that they where computed separatly for each participant

Comment: while your solution works in general, I can't get around the fact, that I need to compute residuals for each subject separately. As per your example: add: `c<-rnorm(1:2,10)` and then compute `mylm <- lm(a~b)
mylm.zresid<-rstandard(mylm)` for each level of c